# Django - text input resulting in wierd characters when rendering template

Tags: python, django, utf-8

I'm not sure what to search for exactly so i'm hoping the community can point me in the right direction.

I have a modelform in my site, with text input.
in one of those inputs, someone copied and pasted the text

> Vancouver marketing extraordinaire Bob Rennie asks “What if it’s not a
>   bubble?

from this link
http://blog.buzzbuzzhome.com/2012/05/vancouver-marketing-bob-rennie-bubble.html
You'll notice the quotation marks and apostrophe are are a little different.

Object saved fine.

The problem came when a template rendered outputing that field. I got:

> Vancouver marketing extraordinaire Bob Rennie asks 1CWhat if it 19s
>   not a bubble?

(notice the **1C** and **19s** where the quotation mark and the apostrophe should be)

I thought it might be a utf-8 issue but i already have this in the top of my html files

```
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
```

Comment: "Object saved fine." Prove it.

Comment: i did. no errors were generated and i looked at the relevant entry in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think before you return a response, you should encode the unicode string first.

```
In [17]: from django.template import Template, Context                                                                                                                   

In [18]: t = Template("{{ text }}")

In [19]: c = Context({'text': 'Vancouver marketing extraordinaire Bob Rennie asks “What if it’s not a bubble?'})                                                         

In [20]: print t.render(c)
Vancouver marketing extraordinaire Bob Rennie asks “What if it’s not a bubble?

In [21]: t.render(c)
Out[21]: u'Vancouver marketing extraordinaire Bob Rennie asks \u201cWhat if it\u2019s not a bubble?'
```

when I write `t.render(c).encode('utf-8')` to a html file and add other meta infomations, it displays [image]

Comment: Ah thanks! Turns out it was because for a specific part of the app i was using the render_to_string method. Encoding the output fixed it right up. Thanks.